# Copy/Paste in Developer Tools crashes Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I mostly change css element's values in 'Elements' tab and when I copy from whole text (of for example a css file) from 'Sources' tab, Chrome crashes commonly.

I noticed that when Chrome crashes it's not able to use clipboard.

What should I do?

```
Google Chrome   47.0.2526.111 (Official Build) m (32-bit)
Revision        88b253bb9dc57f80dc576f296dcf5e5df5cfb7b6-refs/branch-heads/2526@{#545}
OS              Windows 
Blink           537.36 (@88b253bb9dc57f80dc576f296dcf5e5df5cfb7b6)
JavaScript      V8 4.7.80.31
Flash           20.0.0.286
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have VncViewer or such a software,uncheck copy and paste from vnc server.

[image: VNC Preferences]

It has fixed this issue from my end. Funny enough Firefox was still working well. However Chrome and outlook were freezing

Answer (score -2):

Try removing and reinstalling it. You can save your bookmarks by exporting them.